# How are smoke cells an example of Brownian motion?

Tags: kinetic-theory, brownian-motion

I don't get how smoke cells are an example of Brownian motion.

Answer (score 2):

The smoke is a mixture of air and tiny 'dust' particles, which are much larger than the air molecules and undergo Brownian motion. Watching the dust particles under a microscope in a smoke cell (where the smoke is at rest), one can directly observe this Brownian motion.